# Implementing EFFICIENTLY a riak pre-commit hook that does get and put

Tags: erlang, performance, hook, commit, riak

I implemented a pre-commit hook for riak which gets and updates a specific "meta" key whenever commits satisfy a specific criteria. I have noticed however, that doing Client:get to retrieve the "meta" key takes long, and seriously slows down my commits (about 20 times slower). Are there any advices on how to do this correctly? I currently call riak:local_client in the commit hook and then do riak_client:get.

Comment: Code Please. Otherwise it will be hard to help you.

Comment: I have already found out what causes the slow down. It is caused by the fact that I do gets/puts on the same field from the pre-commit hook and use a different local_client() every time. I am not yet sure how to solve it though.

Comment: You might want to answer your question with your code. I'd be really interested in seeing it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the riakc_client in a pre-commit hook will be slow even if you reuse the client.

If you are updating the user metadata on the record being committed, you should be able to just modify the object passed into the pre-commit hook and not have to use riakc_client at all.

If you however update other "meta" records based on the record being commited, it may make sense to instead perform this update in a post-commit hook instead as this should reduce you latency.